# How to search a string in String array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to search a string in the string array. I dont want to use any for looping in it

```
string [] arr = {"One","Two","Three"};

string theString = "One"
```

I need to check whether theString variable is present in arr.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Every method, mentioned earlier does looping either internally or externally, so it is not really important how to implement it. Here another example of finding all references of target string

```
       string [] arr = {"One","Two","Three"};
       var target = "One";
       var results = Array.FindAll(arr, s => s.Equals(target));
```

Comment: Array.Exists() is better I think.

Comment: This is appropriate answer to filter for array with searchterm

Answer (score 141):

Well, something is going to have to look, and looping is more efficient than recursion (since tail-end recursion isn't fully implemented)... so if you just don't want to loop yourself, then either of:

```
bool has = arr.Contains(var); // .NET 3.5
```

or

```
bool has = Array.IndexOf(arr, var) >= 0;
```

For info: **avoid names like var** - this is a keyword in C# 3.0.

Answer (score 29):

Does it have to be a string[] ?  A List<String> would give you what you need.

```
List<String> testing = new List<String>();
testing.Add("One");
testing.Add("Two");
testing.Add("Three");
testing.Add("Mouse");
bool inList = testing.Contains("Mouse");
```

Answer (score 17):

```
bool exists = arr.Contains("One");
```

Answer (score 12):

I think it is better to use ***Array.Exists*** than *Array.FindAll*.

Answer (score 11):

Its pretty simple. I always use this code to search string from a string array

```
string[] stringArray = { "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4" };
string value = "text3";
int pos = Array.IndexOf(stringArray, value);
if (pos > -1)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If the array is sorted, you can use [BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch.aspx). This is a O(log n) operation, so it is faster as looping. If you need to apply multiple searches and speed is a concern, you could sort it (or a copy) before using it.

Answer (score 5):

Each class implementing IList has a method [Contains(Object value)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.contains.aspx). And so does System.Array.

Comment: Note that with the 2.0 generic containers, this is on ICollection<T>; same idea though

Answer (score 4):

Why the prohibition "I don't want to use any looping"? That's the most obvious solution. When given the chance to be obvious, take it!

Note that calls like `arr.Contains(...)` are still going to *loop*, it just won't be you who has written the loop.

Have you considered an alternate representation that's more amenable to searching?

- A good Set implementation would perform well. (HashSet, TreeSet or the local equivalent).
- If you can be sure that `arr` is sorted, you could use binary search (which would need to recurse or loop, but not as often as a straight linear search).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hy2xwa(v=vs.110).aspx) method of Array type. From .NET 3.5 and higher.

```
public static T Find<T>(
    T[] array,
    Predicate<T> match
)
```

Here is some examples:

```
// we search an array of strings for a name containing the letter “a”:
static void Main()
{
  string[] names = { "Rodney", "Jack", "Jill" };
  string match = Array.Find (names, ContainsA);
  Console.WriteLine (match);     // Jack
}
static bool ContainsA (string name) { return name.Contains ("a"); }
```

Here’s the same code shortened with an anonymous method:

```
string[] names = { "Rodney", "Jack", "Jill" };
string match = Array.Find (names, delegate (string name)
  { return name.Contains ("a"); } ); // Jack
```

A lambda expression shortens it further:

```
string[] names = { "Rodney", "Jack", "Jill" };
string match = Array.Find (names, n => n.Contains ("a"));     // Jack
```

Answer (score 2):

At first shot, I could come up with something like this (but it's pseudo code and assuming you cannot use any .NET built-in libaries). Might require a bit of tweaking and re-thinking, but should be good enough for a head-start, maybe?

```
int findString(String var, String[] stringArray, int currentIndex, int stringMaxIndex)
    {
    if currentIndex > stringMaxIndex 
       return (-stringMaxIndex-1);
    else if var==arr[currentIndex] //or use any string comparison op or function
       return 0;
    else 
       return findString(var, stringArray, currentIndex++, stringMaxIndex) + 1 ;
    }



    //calling code
    int index = findString(var, arr, 0, getMaxIndex(arr));

    if index == -1 printOnScreen("Not found");
    else printOnScreen("Found on index: " + index);
```

Answer (score 2):

In C#, if you can use an ArrayList, you can use the Contains method, which returns a boolean:

```
if MyArrayList.Contains("One")
```

Comment: in .NET 2.0, always prefer List<T> over ArrayList. A List<string> would do the same, but with better type-safety, and more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the element existence by

```
arr.Any(x => x == "One")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that no one suggested using `Array.IndexOf` Method.

Indeed, `Array.IndexOf` has two advantages :

- It allows searching if an element is included into an array,
- It gets at the same time the index into the array.

```
int stringIndex = Array.IndexOf(arr, theString);
if (stringIndex >= 0)
{
    // theString has been found
}
```

Inline version :

```
if (Array.IndexOf(arr, theString) >= 0)
{
    // theString has been found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is old one ,but this is the way i do it ,

`enter code here`var result = Array.Find(names, element => element == "One");

Answer (score 0):

Using `Contains()`

```
string [] SomeArray = {"One","Two","Three"};
bool IsExist = SomeArray.Contains("One");
Console.WriteLine("Is string exist: "+ IsExist);
```

Using `Find()`

```
string [] SomeArray = {"One","Two","Three"};
var result = Array.Find(SomeArray, element => element == "One");
Console.WriteLine("Required string is: "+ result);
```

Another simple & traditional way, very useful for beginners to build logic.

```
string [] SomeArray = {"One","Two","Three"};
foreach (string value in SomeArray) {
    if (value == "One") { 
        Console.WriteLine("Required string is: "+ value);
    }
 }
```