# If Statement With Array

Tags: c#, console-application

Instead of writing multiple `if()` statements, is there a way to do something like the below?

```
string redlight = "Larry";
string[] names = { "Joe", "Jack", "Bob", "Larry", "Alpha", "Mick", "Lance", "Ben" };

if (redlight == names)
    Console.WriteLine("It's in the array");
```

Comment: what is `redlight` here?

Comment: string variable, let me edit

Comment: `if (names.Contains(redlight))`

Comment: How strict do you need to be? if redlight = "joe", do you want to match "Joe" in the array?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - yes, ideally I need case not to matter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264962/how-to-search-a-string-in-string-array

Comment: What about some extra whitespace here and there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search a string in String array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264962/how-to-search-a-string-in-string-array)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - if there is whitespace it should still match.  I guess a better way would be using LIKE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `.Contains()`

```
if (names.Contains(redlight))
    Console.WriteLine("It's in the array");
else
    Console.WriteLine("It's not in the array");
```

or `.Any()`

```
if (names.Any(x=>x==redlight))
   Console.WriteLine("It's in the array");
else
   Console.WriteLine("It's not in the array");
```

Checkout this [Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/98mmXP)

Comment: What does x represent in the .Any() example

Comment: It will internally iterate the collection so `x` will be an item of the collection, you can read more about `.Any()` from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx)