# How can I find a phrase anywhere in a String Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, full-text-search

I need to see if any phrase, such as "duckbilled platypus" appears in a string array.

In the case I'm testing, the phrase does exist in the string list, as shown here:

[image]

Yet, when I look for that phrase, as shown here:

[image]

...it fails to find it. I never get past the "if (found)" gauntlet in the code below.

Here is the code that I'm using to try to traverse through the contents of one doc to see if any phrase (two words or more) are found in both documents:

```
private void FindAndStorePhrasesFoundInBothDocs()
{
    string[] doc1StrArray;
    string[] doc2StrArray;
    slPhrasesFoundInBothDocs = new List<string>();
    slAllDoc1Words = new List<string>();
    int iCountOfWordsInDoc1 = 0;
    int iSearchStartIndex = 0;
    int iSearchEndIndex = 1;
    string sDoc1PhraseToSearchForInDoc2;
    string sFoundPhrase;
    bool found;
    int iLastWordIndexReached = iSearchEndIndex; 
    try
    {
        doc1StrArray = File.ReadAllLines(sDoc1Path, Encoding.UTF8);
        doc2StrArray = File.ReadAllLines(sDoc2Path, Encoding.UTF8);
        foreach (string line in doc1StrArray)
        {
            string[] subLines = line.Split();
            foreach (string whirred in subLines)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(whirred)) continue;
                slAllDoc1Words.Add(whirred);
            }
        }
        iCountOfWordsInDoc1 = slAllDoc1Words.Count();
        sDoc1PhraseToSearchForInDoc2 = slAllDoc1Words[iSearchStartIndex] + ' ' + slAllDoc1Words[iSearchEndIndex];
        while (iLastWordIndexReached < iCountOfWordsInDoc1 - 1)
        {
            sFoundPhrase = string.Empty;
            // Search for the phrase from doc1 in doc2;                     
            found = doc2StrArray.Contains(sDoc1PhraseToSearchForInDoc2);
            if (found)
            {
                sFoundPhrase = sDoc1PhraseToSearchForInDoc2;
                iSearchEndIndex++;
                sDoc1PhraseToSearchForInDoc2 = sDoc1PhraseToSearchForInDoc2 + ' ' + slAllDoc1Words[iSearchEndIndex];
            }
            else //if not found, inc vals of BOTH int args and, if sFoundPhrase not null, assign to sDoc1PhraseToSearchForInDoc2 again. 
            {
                iSearchStartIndex = iSearchEndIndex;
                iSearchEndIndex = iSearchStartIndex + 1;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sFoundPhrase)) // add the previous found phrase if there was one
                {
                    slPhrasesFoundInBothDocs.Add(sFoundPhrase);
                }
                sDoc1PhraseToSearchForInDoc2 = slAllDoc1Words[iSearchStartIndex] + ' ' + slAllDoc1Words[iSearchEndIndex];
            } // if/else
            iLastWordIndexReached = iSearchEndIndex;                    
        } // while
    } // try
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("FindAndStorePhrasesFoundInBothDocs(); iSearchStartIndex = " + iSearchStartIndex.ToString() + "iSearchEndIndex = " + iSearchEndIndex.ToString() + " iLastWordIndexReached = " + iLastWordIndexReached.ToString() + " " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

doc2StrArray *does* contain the phrase sought, so why does **doc2StrArray.Contains(sDoc1PhraseToSearchForInDoc2)** fail?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search a string in String array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264962/how-to-search-a-string-in-string-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
found = Array.FindAll(doc2StrArray, s => s.Contains(sDoc1PhraseToSearchForInDoc2));
```

Comment: Close enough - all I had to do was change "FindAll" to "Exists" and it works great. Thanks! I'll bountify ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

In `List<T>`, `Contains()` looking for an T, Here in your code to `found` be `true` must have all the text in particular index (NOT part of it).
Try this

```
var _list = doc2StrArray.ToList();
var found = _list.FirstOrDefault( w => w.Contains( sDoc1PhraseToSearchForInDoc2 ) ) != null;
```